# Computer desktop is gone?

Tags: command-line

After fresh install I updated my elementary os. It said that I have to reboot. I didn't. I installed my amd drivers and then I rebooted. I rebooted it myself I didn't clicked reboot.The e symbol appeared then dissapeared. And then my computer opened as a command line. There was no desktop. Help please !!

Comment: This is happening the second time.İ do t want to format my computer again.

Comment: which graphic card do you have?, maybe is a problem with the proprietary driver

Comment: İts the driver causing this i found but i dont know how to uninstall it

Comment: İts amd crimson 15.12 graphics driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uninstall the propietary driver and install back the open source driver, here are the steps:
turn on the pc and wait until the command line is shown and put this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

put each command one by one (each line is a command).
the first command will complety remove the propietary driver, the second reinstalls the open source driver and the third  one reconfigure the system to use the driver open source.

All these steps are well docuemtned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X%2FTroubleshooting%2FFglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver), if you have a doubt you can check the link for more information

Comment: İ just uninstalled drivers and check the additional drivers part then reinstâll them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart lightdm deamon

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

Come back and confirm if that did work for you.

Comment: İt says "stop" unknown instance

Comment: so just punch in the second statement. The output signify that the daemon isn't running yet

Comment: Ok.But do i have to do this all the time?

Comment: Uh oh.It seems like my computer froze at black screen );

Comment: Maybe your desktop environment would have failed initialization. I use to restart lightdm when my gui shell (Ctrl+Alt+F7) is frozen and rest ttys' work (Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6). Please confirm the persistance of the issue and meanwhile i might try to look into this closely. I currently have very less knowledge on lightdm service.

Comment: @ThetisClena Did the GUI boot up to login screen (in gui mode) or not?

Comment: Uhm it says "start:job start failed" and what is gui im very knowledgeless.

Comment: Like the login screen?

Comment: So there must be problems with your xserver. Try `startx` command at command line and report if there were any errors logged.

Comment: Nothing opened only a command line appeared.İ can log in from the command line

Comment: Fatal server error no screens found bla bla bla unable to connect to xserver.

Comment: Oh and unable to connect to xserver:connection refused sorry.

Comment: Wait ill write errors that i can read

Comment: Modprobe:fatal:module fglrx not found.

Comment: And the others i wrote

Comment: I am linking you to [fglrx-module issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164330/failed-to-load-module-fglrx-module-does-not-exist-0-on-backtrack-5) and [no screens xserver issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712377). Do try to understand what you are doing. Remember in your context, your desktop manager is `lightdm`. Come back if any issues. Update and close this thread when you have completely understood the problem and solution that worked for you. Thanks. have a nice day.

Comment: Oh i found it ! İ think my driver is making all this mess!!!!!But i dont know how to remove it ):

Comment: Thank you.If you werent helping me I was unable to understand my problem.You helped me alot thank you.