# How to uninstall amd graphics driver?

Tags: graphic-drivers

I installed the AMD graphics driver and it made some problems on my computer.
How can I uninstall the AMD graphics driver by terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to remove the driver

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

After running the commands reboot your computer.

WARNING : These commands might destroy your system

Comment: when you do that, you didn't need to reinstall the open source driver?and i think this question is similar to this one 
http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/computer-desktop-is-gone/6805#6805

Comment: Yes, It worked on my laptop.But I'll just add the other commands in case the system is different

Comment: So can you run this from the desktop ?